# How to run two ORACLE SQL Queries together in TOAD?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to run two Oracle SQL queries together inside TOAD.

first query:

```
SELECT * FROM OT_SO_HEAD WHERE SOH_ANNOTATION = 'ECSO10012791'
```

and second:

```
SELECT * FROM OT_SO_ITEM WHERE SOI_SOH_SYS_ID = '30977853'
```

Please guide

Comment: Adding sample data (not as image) would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.
The `UNION` operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

- Every SELECT statement within `UNION` must have the same number of columns
- The columns must also have similar data types
- The columns in every SELECT statement must also be in the same order

Syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

The `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thank you Rezu for your reply. But, I just want to run these two SQL statements differently and get the output differently, instead of executing first SQL statement and then second one.

Answer (score 0):

right click in script window and select EXECUTE -> Execute via Toad Script Runner and reuse Toad

[image]